# Minimalist mouse cursor theme

Tags: mouse, theme, cursor

I'd like to install a X mouse cursor theme like:

[image: Mouse cursor X]

I have Lubuntu with lxappearance, but failed to find an appropriate package for this.

Answer (score 1):

(Update: *including more details after hunting down the old cursors*)

The 'original' X cursors are certainly in the basic packages for X server or X client libraries. It is a font, technically.
(It is in the bitmap font `/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/cursor.pcf.gz` in package `xfonts-base`)

So there is no such package to install these old cursors separately, and you have them already if you have X.

What should exist, though, is a modern "cursor theme" just recreating these cursors in modern format. Maybe it is not aviable as a package, but as a tar.gz file on some desktop theme collection website.
Oh, realizing you did not explicitly ask to use the original/old cursors - so a theme "looking like them" (in a package) would fully solve your question.

Comment: Yes, I have X. But I am not able to assign my mouse cursor to the image above. The customization tool lxappearance only offers DMZ black/white and a couple of others.

Comment: Indeed, lxappearance does not show the original cursors. Seems like they were in a very different format back then; So while they are still there, they are incompatible, (and not automaticaly converted or so, as I expected)

Comment: Ha! Found them... it really is a font, `/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/cursor.pcf.gz`. It is a bitmap font - not scalable, and in an old format. But that is all not surprising as these cursors were part of the very first versions of X pretty sure...

Comment: An interesting hack you could try is provoking LXDE to fall back to use the X11 default cursors. Can you manually try configuring no mouse theme at all, or a nonexisting one? (Btw.: after some searching, I still did not find a modern mouse theme with the old X font cursors.)

Answer (score 1):

I manage to get it working on my Linux.
Basically, I have downloaded the cursor files from http://blackevilweredragon.deviantart.com/art/X11-Cursors-25788898

Then used convert to make ... well convert them to .png

```
convert icon:no.cur normal.png
```

The next step is to make the .png a valid X cursor format, so I used xcursorgen

```
xcursorgen conf.in normal
```

conf.in looks like this:

```
34 10 4 normal.png 1000
```

I did this for all the cursors I was interested in, then overwrite the files in the current cursor theme:

```
root@alexi-XPS13-9333 15:59:40-[x11_cursors]# cp normal /usr/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursors/left_ptr
```

Now it looks like this: [image: X11-defaults]

NOTE: it worth mentioning that some programs will not follow the theme rules (mostly Skype) :)